# How to bring Visual Studio features to Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, eclipse

Visual Studio refugee here.  I've had to switch to Eclipse to write a couple of Java apps and I am really missing all the VS2008 goodness I've come to rely upon.

I am new to Eclipse, so I simply might not be finding what I need.  With that in mind, how do I replicate the following in Eclipse.

1. Right click on a source code tab,
   and open the folder
2. Love VS' External Tools feature, which allows you to perform operations on a single file via tokens.  Anyway to do this in Eclipse?
3. Intellisense when editing XML files

Finally, can someone recommend a good newsgroup or a forum where Eclipse experts hang out (other than here)?  I couldn't really find anything on the eclipse site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There are plug-ins available for this, such as [StartExplorer](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-1225.html), [Eclipse Explorer](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-707.html)
2. Click on the "start button + toolbox" drop down menu next to "run" and "debug" and select "Open External Tools Dialog". This lets you run arbitrary tools.
3. Intellisense for XML would normally be provided by the XML editor you're using. Look in Eclipse Plugin Central for XML plug-ins if the one which come with Eclipse aren't enough for you.

Comment: Thanks, StartExplorer did the trick.  One quick follow-up question.  How do I place the StartExplorer's "Show Resource in Windows Explorer" command onto the toolbar (to avoid having to wade through 150 items on the context menu).

Comment: I don't know, I'm afraid. Can't say I use the toolbars much, so I haven't looked at customizing them.

Comment: I don't know of a way to assign arbitrary toolbar icons, but I haven't tried very hard either.  You're probably better off trying to assign a keyboard shortcut.